# Redundant image drawing with CGContextDrawImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgcontext

I have one image that I wish to redraw repeatedly over the screen, however, there is a large number of redraws per second, and drawing the image each time makes the app take a huge performance hit. Is there a way to somehow cache the CGImageRef or something that would make CGContextDrawImage perform faster?

Comment: Why not make the image a UIImageView?

Comment: It is one image, but it is drawn in many locations across the screen. So it would be many UIImageViews. Also, the content is dynamic, so the location of where these images are drawn changes, so I didn't think using an image view was the right way to go.

Comment: Use Box2d or libraries like that and use a sprite.

Answer (score 1):

Try using UIImageViews and see if it's fast enough.  You are allowed to have many UIImageViews.  You should set all of their image properties to the same instance of UIImage.

If it's for a game, you should just use a game engine (Unity, Cocos2D, etc.).  They have already spent a lot of time figuring out how to make this stuff fast.

Comment: This is for a game, and the content is fairly dynamic, so I dont want to have to deal with adding, moving, and removing all the subviews if I can avoid it.

Comment: Did you try it and see?  Or are you just speculating?

Comment: BTW there's no reason you can't cache UIImageViews and reuse them, like UITableView does with UITableViewCells.

Answer (score 1):

A CGLayerRef should be what you need.

From the Apple docs:

> Layers are suited for the following:
>
> High-quality offscreen rendering of drawing that you plan to reuse.
>
> - For example, you might be building a scene and plan to reuse the same background. Draw the background scene to a layer and then draw the layer whenever you need it. One added benefit is that you don’t need to know color space or device-dependent information to draw to a layer.
> - Repeated drawing. For example, you might want to create a pattern that consists of the same item drawn over and over. Draw the item to a layer and then repeatedly draw the layer, as shown in Figure 12-1. Any Quartz object that you draw repeatedly—including CGPath, CGShading, and CGPDFPage objects—benefits from improved performance if you draw it to a CGLayer. Note that a layer is not just for onscreen drawing; you can use it for graphics contexts that aren’t screen-oriented, such as a PDF graphics context.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH219-TPXREF101